# jQuery tabs into OpenLayers switcher layers

Tags: openlayers-2, jquery

How can I put jQuery UI tabs in openlayers layerswitcher? I can not imagine how this can be done ...

Answer (score 1):

Please check out http://mapquery.org/ which is a jquery wrapper for openlayers might be helpful for you.